# transform output similar to table to string

Tags: r

I have:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b"))
```

This:

```
table(df$x)
```

produces this:

```
a b 
2 1
```

I would like to produce a string with the same information as table like so:

```
a:2 b:1
```

So given a vector (column of a dataframe I suppose). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` :

```
tmp <- table(df$x)
paste(names(tmp), tmp, sep = ':')
#[1] "a:2" "b:1"
```

Or as one string :

```
paste(names(tmp), tmp, sep = ':', collapse = ' ')
[1] "a:2 b:1"
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(cnt = n()) %>% mutate(str = paste0(x,':',cnt)) %>% pull(str)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
[1] "a:2" "b:1"
```